# Merge several files of different length in R based on one column

Tags: r

I have 100 files and each of them looks like this:

```
ID     BYr       Milk         REL
183601 2010 -0.635262171151035 50
183603 2010 -1.15906865500681 50
183611 2010 -0.39135273818727 50
183616 2010 0.832853286113099 50
183619 2010 1.15141619232805 50
```

The column 1 (ID) refers to the animal ID and all files have this column. And the third column is the trait of interest. In this case, milk production or lactation length, etc. 
I want to merge all files based on the variable ID, exclude the columns 2 and 4 and generate a file with all IDs and each trait in a column. Something like this:

```
ID       Milk             LactLength    OP
183601 -0.635262171151035   350          2
183603 -1.15906865500681    250          4
183611 -0.39135273818727    450          5
183616 0.832853286113099    180          6
183619 1.15141619232805     250          7
183623 2.23473028006734     245          8
```

I have tried this from someone's answer:

```
myfiles = list.files(pattern = "\\.txt$")
datlist <- lapply(myfiles,read.table, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, colClasses=c("character", "NULL"))
rowseq <- seq_len( max(vapply(datlist,nrow, integer(1))) )
keylist <- lapply(datlist,function(x) { x[[3]][rowseq] })
names(keylist) <- myfiles
df = do.call(data.frame,keylist)
```

But I am not getting how I can merge the files based on ID. Any help please? Thanks.

Comment: You might be better off with `library(data.table); rbindlist(lapply(myfiles, fread))` with some additional arguments to `fread()`.  It makes it easy to select and drop columns

Comment: If you can provide a sample of at least 2 files it will be easier to test possible answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use join or merge functions in either 'plyr' or 'base' package in R. I however prefer to use 'dplyr' package which has some different types of ways to join dataframes, like left_join, inner_join etc. I guess in your case you could do a full_join and just omit the columns afterwards that you don't want to use, like this:

```
require('dplyr')
first = TRUE

for (file in list.files(pattern = "\\.txt$")){                   #loop over all txt files
    if (first == T){df <- read.table(file,header=T)[,c(-2,-4)];first=FALSE} #don't need to join first file
    else{full_join(df,read.table(file,header=T)[,c(-2,-4)])}}               #join the former and the current dataframes
```

This only works properly when columns you want to merge have the same name and data type.

Comment: Ansjovis86 thanks a lot. However, my problem is actually that the third column of each file has a different name (different trait) and I want to keep them all in the joint file. Is there a way to do that using plyr or base package? Cheers.

Comment: I think this will work if you just pull out columns 1 and 3 from the 2nd data file *before* the full join.

Comment: Full_join will join all new columns, if I'm correct. So like atiretoo said just cut out the 2nd and 4th column before the full_join and it should concatenate all columns by ID. I edited the script. Try that.